# Создание хранимых процедур в sql server management studiо 2012

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос, процедуры

Можете подсказать с хранимыми процедурами? Нас учили, что перед добавлением БД к программе нужно для каждой таблицы сделать хранимую процедуру, `delete`, `update`, `select` и `insert`. Каждую процедуру мы прописывали вручную.

Однако сейчас в таблице около 50 столбцов. Есть ли способ создавать процедуры не вручную ? А то тяжело всё прописывать.

Comment: *Есть способ создать не в ручную процедуры?* Конечно. SSMS прекрасно умеет создавать скрипты создания имеющихся в БД объектов. *нас на парах учили* Как экзамен сдашь - немедленно забудь. Особенно про SELECT - я даже представить не могу, к какой заднице его в этом мероприятии приклеить...

Comment: А для какой цели создавать хранимые процедуры, они дают какой то дополнительный сервис относительно прямого выполнения запросов к таблице ? И 50 колонок в одной таблице выглядят довольно подозрительно, так много колонок не особо часто встречаются

Answer (score 0):

В принципе такого правила не существует, возможно у вас было какое-то особое приложение, которое это требовало. Если вы просто проектируете БД, то нужно создавать только те процедуры, которые выполняют некоторую работу, создавать про запас нет необходимости.